# What is behind the Great Red Spot's longevity?

Tags: jupiter, great-red-spot

On Earth, storms can last a few days. The Great Red Spot on Jupiter is a storm that has been going on for more than 400 years now. What is different on Jupiter that makes it possible for storms to last so long?

Comment: Size,  relative "smoothness" of surface compared with radius,

Comment: It is not sure that the spot first seen in the 17th century is the same as today, as there is a large gap in observations. It is at least 150 years old though, which is already quite long for a storm, at least from our point of view. https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/jupiter-s-great-red-spot-a-swirling-mystery

Comment: [Laboratory simulation of Jupiter's great red spot by rotating shallow water](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0275106202000607)

Comment: [Laboratory simulation of Jupiter's Great Red Spot](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/32020750_Laboratory_simulation_of_Jupiter's_Great_Red_Spot)

Comment: And [here](https://www.slashgear.com/jupiters-spot-is-fading-neptunes-too-20520134/): “Think of the GRS [Great Red Spot] as a spinning wheel that keeps on spinning because it’s caught between two conveyor belts that are moving in opposite directions. The GRS is stable and long-lived, because it’s ‘wedged’ between two jet streams that are moving in opposite directions."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Standard answers, as found  [here](https://earthsky.org/space/jupiters-great-red-spot-shrinking-anticyclone), (partial quote)

> Unlike Jupiter, the Earth has land masses that cause major storms to
> lose energy due to friction with a solid surface. Without this
> feature, Jupiter’s storms are more long-lasting. However, the Great
> Red Spot is long-lived, even by Jupiter standards. Researchers don’t
> quite understand why, but we do know that Jupiter’s storms that are
> located in cloud bands with the same direction of rotation tend to be
> longer lasting.

So, we know some of the probable reasons, and don't know the full story yet.  Keep in mind that the current RedSpot might be a 3-sigma event, even for Jupiter.