# Time evolution data of the Great Red Spot on Jupiter?

Tags: coordinate, jupiter, data-analysis, modeling, great-red-spot

Jupiter's [Great Red Spot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Red_Spot) fascinates scientists for ages, so it does me. Where can I find a table (e.g. as CSV-file) with the **time evolution of longitude, latitude, horizontal and vertical extension of the Great Red Spot?** I am sure somebody did already invest the time to extract such a time series from all available (historical) records and images, but it
looks like I am searching a needle in a haystack.

#### References

There is dozends of nice images and other sources around, for instance:

- [Why is the great red spot shrinking?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35622/why-is-the-great-red-spot-shrinking)
- [What is behind the Great Red Spot's longevity?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39290/what-is-behind-the-great-red-spots-longevity)
- [How is the height of the Great Red Spot measured?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39482/how-is-the-height-of-the-great-red-spot-measured)
- NASA, 2018: [Jupiter's Great Red Spot Getting Taller as it Shrinks, NASA Team Finds](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2018/jupiters-great-red-spot-getting-taller-as-it-shrinks)
- Emmanuel Kardasis *et. al.*: [The need for Professional-Amateur collaborations in studies of Jupiter and Saturn](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274252912_The_need_for_Professional-Amateur_collaborations_in_studies_of_Jupiter_and_Saturn/figures?lo=1)
- projectpluto.com: [Great Red Spot transit times, 2021](https://www.projectpluto.com/jeve_grs.htm)

Longitude and latitude on Jupiter is not so trivial, see F. Bagenal & R. J. Wilson: [Jupiter Coordinate Systems](https://lasp.colorado.edu/home/mop/files/2015/02/CoOrd_systems7.pdf) from 2016.

Comment: The NASA 2018 page leads to this paper: https://doi.org/10.3847/1538-3881/aaae01 The data for Figure 2 (variations in size and drift rate since 1880) is available as a txt file, but you could easily convert it to csv format.

Comment: Wow, that's a good start. What about the position of the spot (relative to magnetic reference frame)? That should exist only since recently.

Comment: No luck so far...

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival any more luck? There's currently a bounty on this question.

Comment: @uhoh Once again thanks for your gratitude.